# Ionic React Android nativ back button doesn't change view

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, routes, ionic5

I have a problem with the native back button on Android with my Ionic-React Project. `IONIC 5`

If I tap on the back button I see that the first Tab in my Mobile-App is highlighted but the view doesn't change.
So I created a new project with the ionic-cli and tested it, usually this works fine. I make a diff to inspect whats I do wrong but i can't figure it out.

did anyone know this problem and can please help me.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- deleting node modules
- reboot my mac
- update ionic `npm i -g @ionic/cli`
- dont forget `npm install`

that works for me